# what is the meaning of \ | in a map vim command?

Tags: vim

Here is a map  command.

```
nnoremap <F5> :w\|!R %<CR>
```

1.what is the meaning of \  here?
2. does | mean pipe  ?

Comment: Lets make this fun. Forget saving the buffer! Just pipe the buffer into R. Like this: `:w !R -f -` or pipe the buffer contents into a new split like this: `:pedit [Results]|wincmd P|setl bt=nofile bh=delete noswf nobl|call setline(1, getbufline('#', 1, '$'))
|%!R -f -`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `|` character separates two Ex commands, see `:help :|`. It's like `;` in programming languages like C and Java. It has nothing to do with pipes; Vim hasn't that concept (which is typically found in shells).

It is escaped here so that the entire command sequence belongs to the mapping; i.e. it maps to `:w|!R %<CR>`. Without escaping, Vim would execute the following instead:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :w
:!R %<CR>
```

Note that you can also write `<Bar>` (cp. `:help key-notation`) instead of `\|`, and the former is more frequently used.

Comment: you are faster Ingo! ^_^ +1  and `:h map_bar` explained it too.

Comment: Thanks @Kent, good to see you lurking around here, too; I really have to apply my advanced Vim editing skills to be faster than you :-)

Comment: I wrote a similar answer, just about to post,  SO noticed me "there is a new answer". you are 19 seconds faster than me. If one day you wrote a post-so-answer vim plugin, you must let me know!

Comment: what a pity,i know the meaning of characters, but  found that `nnoremap <F5> :w\|!R %<CR>` can't make R run from vim,please try it.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Well, `nnoremap <F5> :w\|!echo %<CR>` surely works for me; please don't start new questions in the comments!